# How to assign a section to a specific node with Workbench?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-permissions

I'm creating nodes using a custom modules

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = $link['content_type'];

node_object_prepare($node);

$node->uid = $user->uid;
$node->name = $user->name;

$node->title = $html['title'];
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
$node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = $html['html'];
$node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = $html['summary'];
$node->body[$node->language][0]['format'] = 'filtered_html';

$node->menu['enabled'] = 0; // 1 to enable providing a link in main menu
$node->menu['link_title'] = urlencode($html['title']);
$node->menu['description'] = urlencode($html['summary']);
$node->menu['parent'] = 'main-menu:0';

$node->menu['weight'] = 5;
$node->path['alias'] = urlencode($html['title']) . time();
$node->comment = 1;

$node->status = 1;        // 1 means published
$node->promote = 0;
$node->revision = 0;

$node->changed = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
$node->created = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];

node_submit($node);
@node_save($node);

$node->path['alias'] .= '+' . $node->nid;

node_submit($node);
@node_save($node);

db_update('node_revision')
    ->fields(array('uid' => $node->uid))
    ->condition('vid', $node->vid)
    ->execute();
```

But now I need to assign each node a I create a workbench section, so I tried doing this:

```
$node->workbench_access = array('66');

node_submit($node);
@node_save($node);

$node->path['alias'] .= '+' . $node->nid;

node_submit($node);
@node_save($node);

db_update('node_revision')
    ->fields(array('uid' => $node->uid))
    ->condition('vid', $node->vid)
    ->execute();
```

This add the workbench access id temporarily, but when the page is refreshed it doesn't apply it. Is there a way to assign a node to a workbench section using php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just installed this module for the first time today funnily enough, it looks good :-)

Having a look at the `workbench_access_node_insert()` function (in the `workbench_access.module` file) it looks like the node object key it's looking for is `workbench_access_id`, not `workbench_access`.

Also you need to provide an access scheme (either `menu` or `taxonomy` depending on what access scheme you've chosen at `admin/config/workbench/access/settings`). I think your code should look a bit like this:

```
$node->workbench_access_scheme['access_scheme'] = 'taxonomy'; // or 'menu'
$node->workbench_access_id = array('66');
```

That's untested but looking at the module file it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I kinda seemed to do something similar the function already is doing. After I saved the node, I added the node id, taxonomoy id (access_id), and access scheme, to the table 'workbench_access_node'.


So then this is what my code looks like:

    db_insert('workbench_access_node')
        ->fields(array(
            'nid' => $node->nid,
            'access_id' => $tid,
            'access_scheme' => 'taxonomy',
        ))
        ->execute();

Answer (score 0):

The following line didn't work for me.

```
$node->workbench_access_id = array('66');
```

It worked when I changed it to

```
$node->workbench_access = array('66');
```

Comment: Please consider to add this to the comment but not to the question answer. Thanks!